# AngularJS calling a function once I've made an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, ngresource

**Background**

I am making a angularJS app

I have an object called a Map. The Map has an array of Transforms IDs.

I need to fetch each transform in the Maps's array, then save these to an array of Transforms instead of an array of Transform IDs. So far, I have this done, except calling the function at the correct time.

I want to call a function: `doStuffWithTransformArray` using the completed array.

**Question**

How do I call a function only when the array is finished being filled?

**Current Code (this only works sometimes)**

```
    $scope.makeTransformArray = function () {
        $scope.transforms = [];
        $scope.map.transforms.forEach(function(eachTransformID, index) {
            Transform.get({uuid: eachTransformID.uuid}, function(transformResult) {
                $scope.transforms[index] = transformResult;
                if ($scope.transforms.length == $scope.map.transforms.length) {
                    $scope.doStuffWithTransformArray($scope.transforms);
                    return;
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

**Problem**

This current code will work only when the last Transform in the Map's array finishes last.

It will call the `doStuffWithTransformArray` twice if when the array is filled like this: `(5) [y, y, y, empty, y]`

The fourth one is not yet filled but the fifth finished.

**EDIT 1**

Here is my transform Service:

```
angular.module('serviceregistryApp')
.factory('Transform', function ($resource) {
    var url = 'api/v1/transform/:uuid';
    return $resource(url, {transform: '@transform',  uuid: '@uuid'}, {
        'save': {method: 'POST', headers: {"Authorization": "ABC"}},
        'delete': {method: 'DELETE', headers: {"Authorization": "ABC"}},
        'post': {method: 'POST', headers: {"Authorization": "ABC"}},
        'get': {
            method: 'GET', isArray: false, 
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "ABC"
            }, url: "api/v1/transform/:uuid",
            transformResponse: function (data) {
                return JSON.parse(data);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT 2**

As suggested in the comments, this seems to work, but I find it kinda ugly.

```
    $scope.makeTransformArray = function () {
        $scope.transforms = [];
        var counter = 0;
        $scope.map.transforms.forEach(function(eachTransformID, index) {
            Transform.get({uuid: eachTransformID.uuid}, function(transformResult) {
                $scope.transforms[index] = transformResult;
                counter = counter + 1;
                if (counter == $scope.map.transforms.length) {
                    $scope.doStuffWithTransformArray($scope.transforms);
                    return;
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: It seems like the easiest thing to do would be to increment a counter every time a Transform finishes, then call your `doStuff` function when the counter equals your expected length.

Comment: As a hint when working with AngularJS, not everything needs to be attached to $scope. $scope should really only be worked with when you have the need to attach something directly to the browser; i.e. click events and direct bindings. All of the other work can be done in normal JavaScript functions totally outside of a scoped event. It makes things much easier to understand when  you're trying to figure out a complex problem.

Comment: Is it possible to change the implementation of ```Transform.get(...)```? If you could make it return a promise resolving ```transformResult``` await/async can be used here to make sure the call of ```doStuffWithTransformArray(...)``` will happen only if the for-each loop is done.

Comment: @DavidMichaelHuber Tranform.get is implemented by Angular's built in CRUD library $resource. I have added the service in EDIT 1

Answer (score 0):

[NgResource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) instances have an attached property named `$promise` that can be used for transforming results after they arrive from the server:

```
$scope.object = Transform.get({uuid: eachTransformID.uuid});
var promise = $scope.object.$promise;
var newPromise = promise
  .then(function(object) {
     var obj2 = transform(object);
     $scope.object = angular.copy(obj2);
     return obj2;
}).catch(function(errorResponse) {
     console.log("ERROR", errorResponse.status);
     throw errorResponse;
});
$scope.object.$promise = newPromise;
```

Use the promise for subsequent chaining or consolidation with [$q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all).